# automating microsoft bot testing

Tags: botframework

I am trying to come up with a way to automate the testing of a bot im making with the bot framework. I have used the emulator which is great, but I am wanting to automate things a bit. From my research I have found botium which seems like a great tool, but i get pretty lost when looking through the documentation. I have also heard about using the directline api. Again though, my lack of understanding is getting in the way. Does anyone know if there is a way to connect to the bot using REST? for example, my ideal scenario would be to use a csv file to feed inputs and expected outputs for the bot. I would like to cycle through the file, passing an input to the bot and checking if the response matches my expected output. I am thinking about doing this in powershell because I have some experience there, but im not sure how to start. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The answers above are pretty good, but don't forget to test how well, your Microsoft LUIS is performing with your training data. THere are a number of technique describe there
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49528498/automate-performance-testing-of-chatbot/54462585#54462585 Benoit

Comment: botmonkey.io is an option, but they do not support some advanced payloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know if there is a way to connect to the bot using REST?

You can use [the Direct Line API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to send/receive activities to/from the bot.

> my ideal scenario would be to use a csv file to feed inputs and expected outputs for the bot. I would like to cycle through the file, passing an input to the bot and checking if the response matches my expected output. I am thinking about doing this in powershell because I have some experience there, but im not sure how to start.

Based on you requirement, I write the following scripts to achieve it, you can refer to it.

```
$directline_secert = "your_directline_secret"
$conversation_Id = ""
$filepath = "d:\testmes.csv"
$botId = "You_bot_id"


function StartConversation([string]$directlinesecert){
    $uri = "https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations"

    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + $directlineSecert)

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers
    $global:conversation_Id = $response.conversationId

    Write-Host ("Conversation Id: " + $response.conversationId)
}

function SendActivity([string]$directlineSecert, [string]$conversationId, [string]$mes){
    $uri = "https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/" + $conversationId + "/activities"

    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + $directlineSecert)
    $headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    $Body = @{
    "type" = "message"
    "from" = @{"id" ="user1"}
    "text" = $mes
    } | ConvertTo-Json

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $Body -ContentType 'application/json'


    Write-Host ("Id: " + $Response.id)
}

function ReceiveActivities([string]$directlineSecert, [string]$conversationId){
    $uri = "https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/" + $conversationId + "/activities"

    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + $directlineSecert)


    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $headers


    #Write-Host ("Activities number: " + $Response.activities.Count)

    Foreach($activity in $Response.activities){
      if($activity.type -eq "message" -and $activity.from.id -eq $botId){

        #your code logic to compare received activities with expected result
        Write-Host ("Activities Mes: " + $activity.text)
      }     
    }
}

StartConversation -directlineSecert $directline_secert



#SendActivity -directlineSecert $directline_secert -conversationId '5e5JeKRtG5vBnGIhdip1Hv' -mes 'hi bot' 


Import-CSV $filepath -Header Mes | Foreach-Object{
   #Write-Host $_.Mes

   SendActivity -directlineSecert $directline_secert -conversationId $conversation_Id -mes $_.Mes 
}

ReceiveActivities -directlineSecert $directline_secert -conversationId $conversation_Id
```

*Test result:*

[image]

Comment: thank you so  much! I am working to get my direct line set up and will report back with results. I appreciate the help!

Comment: thank this seemed to work perfectly. I am wondering if you could help with more? I am also trying to do testing for the cards now, do you know if there is a way to receive the json thats returned from a card for validation?

Answer (score 0):

For testing a Bot Framework bot with Botium, there is the Directline-connector available. You can install it with

```
npm install botium-connector-directline3
```

Or you can download the Botium CLI, you won't need to install any additional packages then.

The botium.json file should look like this - you can find the Directline secret key in your Azure account.

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "Directline3 Plugin Sample",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "directline3",
      "DIRECTLINE3_SECRET": "my-directline-secret",
      "DIRECTLINE3_WEBSOCKET": true,
      "DIRECTLINE3_POLLINGINTERVAL": 1000
    }
  }
}
```

The rest is the standard Botium process of writing your conversation files and running it against your chatbot.

```
botium-cli run --config path/to/botium.json --convos path/to/convo_files
```